# MATLAB interpretation of Xcorr2

Tags: matlab, graph, sensors, correlation

I have two vectors of matching lengths. They are readings from two different sensors (one is from a smartphone and the other is from a wiimote) of the same hand movement. I am trying to find the time offset between them to synchronise the readings for further processing. The readings I get are of the format (Time(ms) Value) for accelerations in the X,Y and Z direction.

For the synchronization, I plotted the cross-correlation function `xcorr2()` between the two sets. I am getting the same graph (a weird triangle peak and a straight line at the bottom) for Accelerations along the x, y and z directions (which I guess is good) but I don't know how to interpret it. What do the axes in the graph represent?

Can anyone explain to me what `xcorr2()` means in a qualitative sense. From the correlation function, how do I determine the offset (i.e. how many seconds is sensor1 behind sensor2)?

[image]

Comment: is that even a programming question? I think that question would belong to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn't this qualitative enough http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/xcorr2.html ?

Comment: Note that xcorr2() deals with a pair of 2-dimensional arrays (most often images of some kind).  Your data is 3 streams (x, y and z) of 1-dimensional data.  I would think that you want to perform cross-correlation across a pair of these 1-d streams (I don't think it will matter which one you choose).  In MATLAB, you can use xcorr(), or program it yourself using corrcoef() or completely from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with the comment made above by Predictor.  To align the time series against each-other, I would pick `xcorr()` without the 2.  Consider correlating only the acceleration magnitudes.  For example:

```
a_mag_wii = sqrt(a_x_wii.^2 + a_y_wii.^2 + a_z_wii.^2);
a_mag_phone = sqrt(a_x_phone.^2 + a_y_phone.^2 + a_z_phone.^2);
res = xcorr(a_mag_wiimote, a_mag_smartphone);
```